# Redirect year month day postname permalink structure to category postname structure

Tags: categories, permalinks

I have a Wordpress site with a `/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%/` permalink structure, and now the client wants it changed to `/%category%/%postname%/`.

How do I do a generic redirect for the old permalink structure to the new structure?

I checked out https://yoast.com/wp-content/permalink-helper.php, but it creates redirect code for `/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%/` to `/%postname%/`, instead of to `/%category%/%postname%/`

Comment: That's because it can't be done since old URL do not have sufficient information to create htaccess redirect with category. You will have to so this within wordpress.

Comment: There is redirection plugin. http://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/ and if you prefer not to use plugin then use WordPress function redirect_guess_404_permalink which tries to guess correct URL of 404 error. It mostly works.

Answer (score 1):

Don't need to do anything except change permalink.Just go to 
settings->permalink->Custom Structure and add '/%category%/%postname%/' to text box.
It will work same exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to install plugins to do this. 
Go to Settings-->Permalinks-->Custom Structure--> 
And now set this custom structure

```
www.example.com/%category%/%postname%/
```

It will do all the work of redirecting unless your htaccess has the write permissions.